# Polymer: firebase DB not updating using firebase-element

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to setup a firebase connection with Polymer 1.0:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower/firebase-element/firebase-document.html">

  ...
  <firebase-document id='fstats'
    location="https://polymer-redux.firebaseio.com/stats"
    log="true"
    data="{{stats}}"></firebase-document>
   ...
   this.properties = {
       stats: {
          type: Object,
          observer: '_handleFirebaseStats',
          notify: true
       }
       ...
 _handleFirebaseStats(stats) {
     ...
 }
```

Here is how my firebase db looks like:

```
{
   ...
   stats: { count: 0 }
}
```

Now, inside the `_handleFirebaseStats` I receive `{ count: 0 }`, that part works great. But I would also like to save data back to firebase. I've tried:

```
this.$.fstats.set({count: 2});
this.$.fstats.set({stats: {count: 2}});
this.stats.count = 2;
// etc
```

Anyway, whatever I try in my polymer app, FireBase is never updated. Any suggestions on how to update firebase ?

Comment: try `this.stats = {count: 2}`

Comment: That works, thnx. I was so close :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per my initial assumption **(which was completely wrong)**, I thought the behavior had something to do with [`firebase-document`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-document) element, infact the behavior is well defined inside the [Polymer's Data Binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html) system.

### Solution 1: Replace the whole property.

```
this.stats = {count: 2};
```

### Solution 2: Let the system know a [Path Binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#path-binding) has been updated.

```
this.stats.count = 2;
this.notifyPath('stats.count', this.stats.count);
```

### Solution 3: Let the Polymer handle the path binding stuff for you.

```
this.set('stats.count', 2);
```

Straight from the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path):

> This system “just works” to the extent that changes to object sub-properties occur as a result of being bound to a notifying custom element property that changed. However, sometimes imperative code needs to change an object’s sub- properties directly. As we avoid more sophisticated observation mechanisms such as Object.observe or dirty-checking in order to achieve the best startup and runtime performance cross-platform for the most common use cases, changing an object’s sub-properties directly requires cooperation from the user.
>
> Specifically, Polymer provides two methods that allow such changes to be notified to the system: notifyPath(path, value) and set(path, value), where path is a string identifying the path (relative to the host element).

***Also there is a [Polycast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GxteaIaj2Q&index=2&list=PLNYkxOF6rcIDdS7HWIC_BYRunV6MHs5xo) where Rob Dodson explains this stuff in great detail.***

Comment: I'm crying with happiness. I'm so glad I found your answer. I've been going crazy for the past 3 hours.