# Polymer 1.0: Forced to reload browser for <firebase-collection> data to automatically populate

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

#### Goal

When I login and logout of my app, I want to automatically load data from my `<firebase-document>` element as follows.

my-settings.html

```
<firebase-document location="[[app.firebase.settings]]"
                   data="{{app.settings}}">
</firebase-document>
```

#### Expected Behavior

From a logged in state, I expect to be able to logout. Then log back in and have `app.settings` automatically populate. In other words:

console.log

```
app == { foo: bar,
         settings: baz
       }
```

#### Actual Behavior

From a logged in state, if I logout then log back in, the `app` object does not contain a `settings` property at all. In other words:

console.log

```
app == { foo: bar }
```

#### Reload Browser as Workaround Hack

As a hack, I'm able to get the expected result **if I first reload the browser**. *logout > reload browser > login* yields the following desired result:

console.log

```
app == { foo: bar,
         settings: baz
       }
```

## Question

What approach should I try to get the `settings` property to automatically populate my `app` object after *logout > login* without having to reload as an intermediate step? i.e., *logout > reload browser > login*.

Is this maybe a lifecycle or registration issue I'm not understanding? Or something else? (I just need a general direction to pursue.)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053971/polymer-1-0-how-to-use-firebase-element/33055607#33055607). Seems like a Path Binding issue.

Comment: @AnkitPopli: Thanks +1. But I'm not sure if that's the issue because according to that answer [and the Rob Dodson video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GxteaIaj2Q), declarative path bindings should auto update as expected.

Comment: @AnkitPopli: My apologies. It *was* (apparently) a path binding issue. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34403783/1640892) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34406738/1640892). But I have NO IDEA why it works when the path binding is removed.

Comment: no problem buddy. I wasn't sure either.

Comment: This might be a special use case of the [path binding feature described in this video](https://youtu.be/0GxteaIaj2Q?t=4m40s) not working? Maybe somebody can explain why not? Or what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try settings instead of app.settings for fixing the value update issue.
For hiding the values you can use a dom-if template and set security read/write rules on Firebase.

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[user]]">
  <firebase-document 
    location="[[app.firebase.settings]]"
    data="{{settings}}">
  </firebase-document>
</template>

<firebase-auth location="[[app.firebase]]" user="{{user}}"></firebase-auth>
```

Comment: This seems to work. ([See my version in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34406738/1640892).) Just not sure why.

Comment: @Mowzer Super! there is no deep binding by default I think, I'll see if there is some documentation.

Comment: This might be a special use case of the [path binding feature described in this video](https://youtu.be/0GxteaIaj2Q?t=4m40s) not working? Maybe somebody can explain why not? Or what might be going on?

Answer (score 2):

[Per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34403783/1640892), the code that works is as follows:

my-settings.html

```
<firebase-document location="[[app.firebase.settings]]"
                   data="{{settings}}">
</firebase-document>
<paper-input value="{{settings.email}}"
             label="Email">
</paper-input>
...
<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-settings',
      properties: {
        app: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true
        },
      settings: {
        type: Object,
        notify: true,
        observer: '_settingsChanged'
      },
      _settingsChanged: function() {
        this.set( 'app.settings', this.settings);
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

my-controller.html

```
<my-settings id="settings"></my-settings>
...
_handleLogout: function() {
  this.$.settings.set('settings', {});
},
```

Comment: This might be a special use case of the [path binding feature described in this video](https://youtu.be/0GxteaIaj2Q?t=4m40s) not working? Maybe somebody can explain why not? Or what might be going on?

Comment: Does this video help?
Rob Dodson Polycasts series episode [Binding to Arrays](https://youtu.be/HBUb8frm2Tw?t=3m45s).

Comment: @GlennVandeuren: Rob's video... helpful? Absolutely. They always are! And much appreciated too. But was it relevant to this particular question? Not so much. Because I'm not trying to bind to an array in this question. Don't you agree?

Comment: True, they always are! In his example he uses an Array butt it's the same explenation for an Object.

Check the note in the [path-binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#path-binding) section.